# Laravel 5.2 - login and user session

Tags: php, laravel-5

This seems to be a very very basic problem to solve but I haven't been able to. Last time I used laravel was like 8 months ago and there are some things that are not working right now with this basic Login - Auth thing.

I'm using laravel 5.2 and here is my login:

**ROUTE:**

```
Route::post('login', [
    'as' => 'post_login',
    'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@login'
]);
```

**Auth\AuthController.php:**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if(Auth::attempt([
        'email' => $request->get('email'), 
        'password' => $request->get('password'), 
        'active' => 1
        ])) 
    {

        $user = Auth::user();

        var_dump($user);

    }
    else 
    {
        return 'Could not log in';
    }
}
```

When I log in with a registered user, it shows me the user properly, for now everyhting goes perfect.

But, the problem is that in the main menu I cannot see the User name instead of the "login" - "register" buttons. Even if I click one of those buttons, nothing happens, the view doesn't change and does nothing.

**My Main Menu Markup:**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">

                <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <!-- Branding Image -->
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    Fotopredio
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @if (Auth::guest())
                        <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="{{ route('registration') }}">Registro</a></li>
                    @else
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                {{ Auth::user()->email }} <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

You can see the @if(Auth::guest()) ... It's not working, even when I log in, I can see the Login and Register buttons, when I click them nothing happens. I can't even logout.

> EDIT

I have this markup in my Welcome page, the page that the user should see after it logs in.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', 'Home')
@section('body')

<?php
if (Auth::check()) {
    echo "Loged In";
} else {
    echo "not loged in";
}
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Welcome</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    Your Application's Landing Page.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And even after I login, It shows `NOT LOGED IN`

Comment: try add elseif(Auth:user()) after the if(Auth::guest())

Comment: I'm gonna update my question so you can see more of what's actually happening

Comment: @Niall as you can see, all the time it has been the POST method (:

Comment: Do you have your route inside the group middleware?

Comment: @Niall just inside the Web Middleware.

Comment: Is your "Welcome" route also in your web middleware? A change to laravel 5.2 means that Sessions are only called/run within that web middleware. So if "Welcome" isn't in the web middleware, you won't be logged in. (Matt has a good link about this change : https://mattstauffer.co/blog/middleware-groups-in-laravel-5-2)

Comment: @Icehawg that was it. Look, if you can post this comment as an Answer I can check it as the definitive. I have all my routes inside my Web middleware except for this one. Silly me, still not used to this 5.2 changes. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Welcome` route also needs to be in your web *middleware*. A change to **laravel 5.2** means that Sessions are only called/run within that web *middleware*.

So if `Welcome` isn't in the web *middleware*, you won't be logged in. (Matt has a good link about this change [here](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/middleware-groups-in-laravel-5-2/))